# I am not receiving mails send from JAVA

Tags: java, spring, server, jakarta-mail, jhipster

I want to send an email from out java application and I configured everything according to the documentation. So here are my mail configuration placed in **application-dev.yml** (username and password are not needed - I checked with the colleagues from system administration)

```
mail:
    host: xx.x.x.xxx //we are using the company mail host
    port: 25
    protocol: smtp
messages:
    cache-seconds: 1
thymeleaf:
    cache: false
http:
    encoding:
        charset: UTF-8
        enabled: true
        force: true
```

Here is my java code:

```
MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, 
                           isMultipart, CharEncoding.UTF_8);
message.setTo("myemail@company.com");
message.setFrom(jHipsterProperties.getMail().getFrom());
message.setSubject("Test");
message.setText("Hello World!", true);
javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
```

I don't get any errors in java, so everything should be ok, but I am not receiving the email.

I thought at the beginning that it is a problem on the server side, but we tried to send an email from the command line and the email was received. The command line was:

```
SendSMTP.exe /nos /host XX.X.X.XXX /from emailAddress@company.com /to myemail@company.com /subject test /body 123
```

Maybe someone had this problem already, because I can't find any solution on the internet.

Comment: Try to set debug mode on that package. You might get some clue logging.level.org.springframework.mail=DEBUG

Comment: I would guess that your mail gets detected as spam

Comment: the worst case.. `javaMailSender.send(mimeMsg);` is not being called :P hehe..

Comment: Can you try with a docker configuration as explained at JHipster Tips n Trick [link](https://jhipster.github.io/tips/015_tip_local_smtp_server.html)

Comment: I checked of course the spam, and no mail is there

Comment: Is the value of `jHipsterProperties.getMail().getFrom()` a valid email from your company? The server of your company may not allow sending emails if the from field is not from your comapny.

Comment: Nah it might not even hit your spam folder but will bounce off directly. You might want to authenticate your mail like so http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0538.html

Comment: Try setting mail.debug to true in your yml file and post the JavaMail debug output.

Comment: Can you please paste the console output?